# Resources for learning VBA Programming in Excel (for a complete programming newbie)

Tags: excel, vba

A friend of mine spends long hours on Excel, and wishes to learn VBA for Excel. He has no experience coding whatsover. What are the best resources (links/books) available?

Answer (score 4):

The best resource for getting going is the **Macro recorder**.  Run it while using Excel and it will generate code to reproduce what you've just done.  Looking through and playing with the generated code is a nice way of getting a feel for VBA - both the language and the underlying structures.

There's a nice introduction at http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/record-modify-run-excel-macro.php and some instructions for Excel 2010 at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814737.aspx.

The **Excel VBA Programming for Dummies** book (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Excel-VBA-Programming-Dummies-Computers/dp/0470503696/) is one of the better Dummies books (admittedly the version I read was a few years ago now) - the author does know his stuff.  He also maintains a pretty good Excel site, the VBA section is at http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/C33.

Comment: The macro recorder is good for getting a feel of the structure/syntax of VBA, but it does produce some truly horrible and inefficient code (lots of Selection... etcetera). I'd also think about looking into good coding practices (largely language unspecific). Most of all though... Don't be afraid and just start coding, see where it leads you!

Comment: True, I wouldn't use it to learn Design Patterns!  When you're just starting out though it's usually syntax and structures you're getting to grips with first.

Answer (score 2):

Pick your favorite:

http://www.excel-vba.com/excel-vba-contents.htm

http://www.vbtutor.net/VBA/vba_tutorial.html

http://www.anthony-vba.kefra.com/

Here's a similar question asked before on SO:

[VBA: Basic Syntax and Examples Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292348/vba-tutorial)

And not to forget: tell him about this site, if he has specific questions, he should ask them here on SO.