# Excel: How to find out value from table that is missing in database

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-statements, messagebox

I'm trying to make some code that takes data from a table and compares it with data in another table.

I have two tables. The first one contains all my customers, the second is a kind of Excel database which contains the names of customers and amount of sold goods.

I was trying to find out the way for making a message box that would show which customer from table 2 is missing in table 1 after pressing a command button.

[image: IDEA]

I tried to do something in VBA, but I'm not too skilled to make that.

Comment: "*I tried to do something in VBA, but I'm not too skiled to make that.*" -- I'm afraid solving a problem using VBA without learning VBA won't work. There are a lot of VBA tutorials out there (try the search engine of your choice), even StackOverflow has something on this topic, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4859955 for example. If you have a specific question concerning your VBA code, feel free to edit your question and show us what you've achieved so far and where you're stuck.

Comment: Is "Table2" = "Customer" or the other way round? Why use VBA for something that can be done with a formula?

Answer (score 3):

Until you get your VBA to the point where you can add it to your question, perhaps an array formula¹ will suffice.

In G2 as an array formula¹,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz",A:A )), MATCH(0, IFERROR(MATCH(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz",A:A )),D:D, 0), COUNTIF(G1:G$1, A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz",A:A )))), 0)), "")
```

Fill down as necessary to catch all missing customer entries.

[image: missing_customers]

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>