# Comparing Worksheet Name string and performing an action

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, worksheet

Below is the code I have so far. I am trying to do the following:

Compare the "ICT number" to the name of worksheet and if that worksheet name contains the ICT number, even if it is mixed in with other string values, then i want to look at a certain cell in that worksheet and compare the value in that cell with a cell in my checklist worksheet.

If those values are the same, then i want to have a message come up in a corresponding cell on that row saying that the two sources reconcile.

I then want this to loop for all of the rows in the checklist worksheet and all of the worksheets in the workbook.

```
Dim ICT_Number As Range
Dim statmentdata As Range
Dim checklistdata As Range
Dim Worksheet As Variant
Dim reconcile As Range

For Each cell In Range("d6:d236")

Set ICT_Number = ActiveCell
Set statementdata = Worksheets("m0017 v p0903").Range("H2016")
Set checklistdata = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)
Set currsheet = Worksheets("m0017 v p0903")
Set reconcile = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11)

If InStr(1, cell, ICT_Number, 1) Then
    If statmentdata = checklistdata Then
        reconclie.Value = "this line reconiles"
    Else
        reconcile.Value = "this line does not reconclie"
    End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: please clean up your code and show us only the relevant procedure and the part of code where you need help. Your question is really a mess for now.

Comment: Hi Jmax, The  section in deed help with is ` If currsheet.Name = ICT_Number Then

If statmentdata = checklistdata Then reconclie = "this line reconiles"

    Else

    reconcile = "this line does not reconclie"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues in your code:

#### Don't use protected (or ambiguous) names for your variables.

Please DON'T DO:

```
Dim Worksheet As Variant
```

Better do:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
```

#### Use `Set` when assigning an object

This WON'T work:

```
currsheet = Worksheets("statement n0246 v ab119")
```

Instead, do:

```
Set currsheet = Worksheets("statement n0246 v ab119")
```

#### What your code could look like

```
Sub test()

Dim ICT_Number As Range
Dim statmentdata As Range
Dim checklistdata As Range
Dim Worksheet As Variant
Dim reconcile As Range

Set ICT_Number = Worksheets("checklist").Range("D79")
Set statementdata = Worksheets("n0246 v ab119").Range("H2016")
Set checklistdata = Worksheets("checklist").Range("H79")
Set currsheet = Worksheets("statement n0246 v ab119")
Set reconcile = Worksheets("checklist").Range("N79")

If currsheet.Name = ICT_Number Then
    If statmentdata = checklistdata Then
        reconclie.Value = "this line reconiles"
    Else
        reconcile.Value = "this line does not reconclie"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

#### Before anything else

Please have a look at a VBA Tutorial to **learn the syntax**: [VBA: Basic Syntax and Examples Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292348/vba-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks JMax, i have used two if then statements and this also does not seem to be working, how would i determine criteria with an if statement and then take an action?

Comment: the task that i am really finding difficult is accessing the string value of the worksheet, i know how to change the value, but how would i access it as it is, store it in a variable and then compare that variable to my ICT variable?

Comment: especially as the exitsing macro generates about 100 seperate statements in the format "statement n0246 v ab119" and the ICT variable will only hold "n0246" how would i compare the ict variable to the worksheet name?

Comment: I've edited my answer, but before anything else, please have a look at a VBA tuto

Comment: and then the last step is looping, i guess once the syntax of making the sub work is complete, to loop i would just use a do until isEmpty (activcell.value) in my checklist worksheet?

Comment: Hi I had a look at tuto and came up with the new code in my post

Comment: used InStr(1, cell, ICT_Number, 1) to look for the workbook name.

Comment: I advise you to ask a new question with your updated code (which looks far better than your first shot) and ask your new question (loop in your case). It is easier when you have 1 topic / 1 question :). Furthermore, users often overlook already answered questions so you will have probably more answers on a new question (especially if I can't come back soon)