# VBA - If Range Includes Value Then Array(i) = 1, Loop, Sum

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA but have previous experience with PHP programming logic and various stats programming syntax.  I am trying to write a code to search through a series of cell ranges for a specific value-- if that value exists in the range I want it to insert a 1 into an array, and if it doesn't to insert a 0.

My data look something like:

```
**Item  R1  R2**
1121    1   3
1121    2   
1121        
1121    3   2
1121    3   
1122    4   5
1122    3   5
1122    5   
1122    4   
1122    5
```

My end goal is to be able to sum the values in the array and count the total number of items with each rating.  For example, in the sample above I would want to be able to produce:

> Number of Items with Rating of 1 = 1
>
> Number of Items with Rating of 2 = 1
>
> Number of Items with Rating of 3 = 2
>
> And so on.

The code I wrote was:

```
Sub Items()

    Dim myArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    i = 0
    k = 0
    R5 = Range("G(2+k):H(6+k)")
    mycount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(myArray)


    Sheets("Operational").Select

    For Each R5 In Range("G2:H206")
        ReDim myArray(0 To i)
        myArray(i) = Cell.Value
        i = i + 1
        k = k + 4

        R5.Select
        If R5.Value = "1" Then
            myArray(i) = 1
        Else
            myArray(i) = 0
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I have 5 rows for each item so I thought I could approach this as a repeating, consistent loop.  However I get an error when I try to run it - "Application-defined or object-defined error."

I know this is probably not the best way and I am so new to this I don't know where to start in troubleshooting.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Also if anyone has a good reference for VBA structure/code or a beginner's tutorial, let me know!  I haven't had much luck in finding any good references.

Comment: Since you *did* ask, [take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/292348/698590) for some starting pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change a few things to make this work out. I've changed/added comments to your code below...

```
Option Explicit ' Helps with ensuring all variables are declared correctly.

' Need to add reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' when using Scripting.Dictionary

Sub Items()

Dim Ratings As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim ItemTracking As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim DictKey As Variant

    ' Use SET to assign objects
    Set Ratings = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:H206") ' The Range takes (in this case) a complete STRING argument, which can be manipulated with variables through concatenation with '&'.

    For Each cell In Ratings ' First column is R1, second is R2, etc.
        If Len(Trim$(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & cell.Row).Value)) > 0 Then ' Make sure we actually have an item before continuing...
            If Val(cell.Value) > 0 Then ' Make sure we have a rating before continuing...
                DictKey = Trim$(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & cell.Row).Value) & "R" & cell.Column - 1 & "V" & Val(cell.Value) ' If you need a more descriptive output than '1121 R1V1`, then just change this to match. Be careful of the string concatenation/variable usage.
                If ItemTracking.Exists(DictKey) Then ' When using a Dictionary (versus a Collection), we have the nifty Exists() function to help us see if we already have something.
                    ' If we do, add to it...
                    ItemTracking.Item(DictKey) = ItemTracking.Item(DictKey) + 1
                Else
                    ' Else, we do not, add it to the Dictionary.
                    ItemTracking.Add DictKey, 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    For Each DictKey In ItemTracking
        Debug.Print DictKey & " - " & ItemTracking.Item(DictKey)
    Next

End Sub
```

I have used the `Scripting.Dictionary` to get this. To use, you'll need to reference the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library (see comments in code). This doesn't do much useful, just prints the results to the immediate window, but you can modify to get what you need, I think.

Answer (score 2):

If I read what you are asking correctly, you can do this very easily and much more simply, without VBA.

Here a screenshot of the solution.

Columns H:K perform a CountIf on each Rating Column for each Item (see formula bar). Column G is a simple Sum of H:K for each rating.

[image]

**UPDATE**

To reflect Ratings by Item, the non-VBA approach becomes this:

[image]

You could re-arrange or modify this to make it prettier, probably. Also, you can get a unique list of Item numbers by coping the Item numbers to a new range and using remove duplicates (XL2007 and above) or Advanced Filter > Unique Values (XL2003). Also, if you are on XL 2003, the CountIFs won't work, you need to use a **=Count(If(** array formula. I can explain if need be.

Comment: While this is not incorrect, it doesn't fully address the question, I think. The OP is also asking for grouping by `Item` (1121, 1122). I could see this with a `VLOOKUP()` added in, but then I feel like that becomes a little more complicated.

Comment: I actually want to find out the frequency of each rating value (1-5) indexed by item number. So if there are multiple ratings of a value for a specific item number, it is only counted once in the final sum. This will present me with a list of the number of items with each rating.  Also, I need to do this for multiple datasets and thus it would be much simpler if I had a script written and didn't have to edit individual cells as much.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure if was what is needed. I edited my posting to reflect rating counts by Item number without VBA, as well.

Comment: Thanks for thinking about this problem!  In order to get the output I need you would then have to count the number of values greater than zero across the items for each rating.  So you could add a simple {=SUM(IF(CR:CR>0,1,0))} array formula for each rating in 5 blank cells to calculate.

Comment: I am confused, how is what I did above different from what your last comment?

Comment: I need a final number indicating the number of items with the comment for each rating.  I don't see anywhere in your spreadsheet where you have taken this last step.  It would look something like: Rating 1 - 2 Items; Rating 2 - 1 Item; Rating 3 - 2 Items; Rating 4 - 2 Items; Rating 5 - 1 Item (using the sample data).

Comment: oh, just insert a row that sums all the ratings for each item. Or, if you are saying you need the actual text **Rating 1 - 2 Items.**,  then you could wrap that around the formula I have in there already - so `="Rating " & H$1 & " - " & [Multiple CountIfs Formulas] & " Items."` If I am still off base, then, you could still play with it. My intent was just to provide a non-vba solution, since these are often better and more user-friendly in the long run.